# How to speed up Babel build in JSPM

Tags: babeljs, jspm

My JSPM build process continues to take longer and longer as I code more of my app. I noticed babel-loader has a `cacheDirectory` option for performance improvements, but babel-loader is for Webpack and not JSPM. Are there any good methods for reducing build times in Babel with JSPM? Thanks.